# Unable to override virtual c# method

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, overriding, virtual

I have the following code

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
public class Parent : IFoo
{
    public virtual void Bar(){}
}
public class Child : Parent, IFoo
{

    public override void Bar(){}

}

IFoo test = new Child();
test.Bar();
```

`test.Bar()` always calls parent method

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile: there can't be the `public` modifier in `IFoo.Bar`. Hence we can't tell what's wrong with your code. Please post the real piece of code stripped down to the core of your problem. Most probably you implement `IFoo.Bar` explicitly in `Parent` and hence the `Child` won't override it.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more code.  This test causes `Child.Bar` to run over here.  (And your interface definition is syntactically incorrect -- interface members don't have visibility specifiers.)

Comment: Your example does not compile. Did you mean to make Parent an abstract class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with overriding virtual c# method (CORRECTED)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371061/problem-with-overriding-virtual-c-method-corrected)

Comment: your code work's fine,it's call the child method .

Answer (score 1):

That should only happen if you implement it explicitly.

I just tested and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar();
}
public class Parent : IFoo
{
    public virtual string Bar() 
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
public class Child : Parent, IFoo
{

    public override string Bar() 
    {
        return "Hello world after override";
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IFoo test = new Child();
    Console.WriteLine(test.Bar());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello world after override
```

Answer (score 0):

WorksForMe: The problem must be somewhere else, when I run this code I see the child method is called, correctly. To compile your code I had to remove "public" from the method in the interface and I gave both Bar() methods a body.

Answer (score 0):

**C# 4.0** says that you have an error in syntax

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}
```

- access modifiers are not valid here
  So, if remove "public", code will run with child version of method as planned by you

Comment: If it doesn't compile, it's not going to run at all.  Therefore this cannot be the real problem.  I suspect the OP has posted fabricated code that is similar to the real code but not close enough for us to diagnose the actual problem.  (And this fabricated code has syntax errors; presumably the real code does not.)

Comment: yes, but in this situation - this is one right solution - syntax error in interface declaration, becouse in all other cases "override" will overrride base method